# Updating a site theme and template

Tags: theme, site-template

I have site where we have made some changes to the SiteTemplate (which consists of the ONET.xml file and 2 .aspx files). We also had to update the site theme (CSS changes mostly) for some of the changes. We have packaged up all the changes in a .wsp package and deployed it, so that for future sites everything should be in order.

I know SharePoint 2007 doesn't propogate changes to existing sites,  so I wrote a script that iterates the sites and replace the two .aspx-files (default.aspx is one) - that should be fine.

The way I updated the theme was to run:

```
SPWeb web = // ... get web ...
web.ApplyTheme("none");
web.Update();
web.ApplyTheme("mytheme");
web.Update();
```

Visually it seems to do the trick, but I want to make sure that there's no old files that haven't been updated, so I'm asking you: Did I forget anything?

Answer (score 1):

If your theme has been deployed in the right directory and is present in the THEMES.XML, you should be ok.